# CalendarList.insert(CalendarListEntry).execute is returning 404

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

There seems to be some issue. This was working in the past but recently stopped working. Trying to subscribe a user to an existing calendar, or in other words inserting an existing calendarId into the CalendarList. The Api documentation says to do the following:

```
CalendarList.insert(CalendarListEntry).execute
```

However this now returns a **404** on the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`

The API Explorer online also gets a **404** when trying to execute it

Comment: Do you get a 404 when executing https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list without specifying any parameters? Or only when inserting a new calendar?

Comment: No, retrieving the calendar list works. Just when inserting  the new calendar

Answer (score 0):

### `404 not found` means either:

- A calendar with the specified `id` does not exist
- The calendar exists, but you do not have the permission to add in to your calendar list

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found).

**If you are want to add a calendar to your calendar list, it must be either**

- yours
- from your domain with the sharing settings `Make available for [NAME OF YOUR DOMAIN]`
- Publicly accessible
- Explicitly shared with you

Comment: Thanks a million. that was the issue

Comment: Very good informations... But where about to share my personal calendar with the Service Account... How to do it ?. I have already try to do this using CalendarList: insert, but I really don't understand how to proceed... Any hints will be very appreciated.